# Axlsx Condition in the formula

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

How I can perform the following condition in Axlsx gem ?

```
=IF(true, 'Yes', 'No')
```

I'm trying like v this, but its not working.

```
sheet.add_row ['male', "=IF(true, 'Yes', 'No')"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix it by removing all the spaces in the formula and condition also